# Runtime Permissions Not Working on Real Device

Tags: android, location, android-permissions, user-permissions

I have implemented RT location permissions in my app and tested on a Nougat device. I have checked the logcat but it looks like the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() and ActivityCompat.requestPermission` dont execute and subsequently onRequestPermissionRationale never gets called but in the device settings for the app, it is always showing as permission granted

I have tried logging like below in code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_home);

    prefsHelper = new SharedPrefsHelper(this);
    initViews();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Log.d(TAG, "BEFORE CHECK");
    checkPerms();

    setUpDrawer();
    prefsHelper.setLoggedOut(false);

    getVehicles();
    handlePlacesInput();

    rideContinueLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validate() && Utils.isNetwork(ClientHomeActivity.this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ClientHomeActivity.this, BookRideActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("start_addr", startAddr);
                intent.putExtra("dest_addr", destAddr);
                startActivity(intent);
                clearInputs();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Enter Start and Drop Locations", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void checkPerms() {
    Log.d(TAG, "DO CHECK");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE CHECK");
        reqPerms();
    }
}

private void reqPerms() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ASKING");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, AppConstants.LOC_PERMS_REQ_CODE);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case AppConstants.LOC_PERMS_REQ_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "GRANTED");
            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission Rationale");
                } else {
                    reqPerms();
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The log stops at `"DO CHECK" tag and other tags after that don't execute`. I am trying to build a location based app. Can anyone tell me why its is happening this way, is it a bug on my device or in code? Thanks.

Comment: what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @Sagar, target api and compilesdk verison are both api level 27

Comment: Is it fresh installation of app?

Comment: No, about a week old app now..still working on it

Comment: Just remove the old app and re-install it will work

Comment: @Andromeda Did u found the answer. Facing same issue only in Samsung device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActivityCompat.requestPermission dont execute and subsequently
>   onRequestPermissionRationale never gets called **but in the device
>   settings for the app, it is always showing as permission granted**

Since your app is old app and you have already granted the necessary permissions to the app, `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` will return `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` and you won't see the permission request again.

If you want to see the permission request, un-install the older app and install a new one. Another way is to just disable the permissions from the settings.

Comment: Thank you for ur help. It's not working, is it a problem with the location widget?

Comment: @Andromeda does your settings still show permission granted?

Comment: @Andromeda that's really strange. Can you try to disable the permission manually? Also update your question with build.gradle file.

Comment: Yes, I have disabled it and it works now. Now, don't know who's answer to accept. Many thanks to you Sagar. God bless y'all

Comment: @Andromeda that's a tough question. Anyways enjoy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
make sure your app level gradle file in compile sdk version latest.
like

```
  compileSdkVersion 27
```

then after also add permission into android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and after check runtime permission like below make two method.

```
/**
 * this method check permission and return current state of permission need.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

/**
 * this method request to permission asked.
 */
private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission was granted. Kick off the process of building and connecting
            // GoogleApiClient.
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            // Permission denied.

        }
    }
}
```

then when call get location method then put like below check

```
 // Check if the user revoked runtime permissions.
    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    }

    buildGoogleApiClient();
```

Comment: I have followed exactly this but no result, I'm starting to think the problem is with my phone as a second app is also facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

The only logical explanation for your code to log "DO CHECK" and not "INSIDE CHECK" is that the permissions are already granted.

Before requesting permissions, if the permissions are already granted, you can do your required operations directly.

Also you can make use of my library to handle runtime permissions easily.
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already granted the permission.

Try to reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is tow possibility to not show permission dialog after request which is bellow.

**Target Version**
Please set your targetSdkVersion in your build great than 23

**Declare permissions Manifest**
Please don't miss to declare permission in manifest which you need and you are requesting at runtime,